# VS Code Python debugging. How to continue from error. Repeat fromline after changes

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

During development it's often happens to me that i have pretty long script execution (which doesn't depend on me), and when error occurs at the late steps it is really annoying to rerun whole script again.
**Is there an option to repeat last line execution after correcting an error?

Or i need to rerun file from beginning again?**
To my understanding of scripting language Python should allow that

Comment: just in case, do you use breakpoints (flags)?

Comment: @Ghanem yes. But here i wouldnt set a breakpoint, because it wasn't predicted error. Like - forgot add self in class, or rename a variable. So you need to rename a variable and go on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-i` flag on the command line if you simply want to drop into a REPL just before exiting your script.

Otherwise you are basically looking for setting a breakpoint at the end of execution with a way to jump back to a set point after most of the execution has already occurred. You can try using "Jump to Cursor" to jump back to where you want to start execution from.

Comment: Is "jump to cursor" has anything with script execution? Or it is just navigation in the file?

Comment: It's like set a point, to start from again, if the script breaks. Not to start from begging

Comment: It basically let you tell the debugger where to start executing next.

Comment: Can you describe in steps how can i do it? Can't find such VS Code feature

Comment: It will be covered in the next blog post at https://aka.ms/pythonblog.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Brett Cannon

Quote from [aka.ms/pythonblog](https://aka.ms/pythonblog)

> When you start a debug session and the debugger hits a breakpoint, you can right click on any part of your code – before or after the point where the breakpoint was hit, and select “Jump to Cursor”. This will make the debugger continue its execution from that selected line onward

So you can hit error and go back, up 5 lines of code for example and redo things

Comment: However, if an exception has been hit, this doesn't allow continuing. If it's a normal breakpoint anywhere, including in a try/except block, then it should work.